# Python queue.py Type Error when using the same Enum

Tags: python, enums, queue

I have a Python queue and Enum. The idea is, that I put values from the Enum instead of numbers, into the Queue to make it more readable. So part of it looks kind of like this:

```
import queue as q
from enum import Enum

Commands = Enum('Commands', 'power_on power_off etc')
queue = q.PriorityQueue(50)

def power_on():
    queue.put(Commands.power_on)
```

Now all of this runs in PyQt5 Threads and is supposed to run for some time. But after using the app for a while, the app crashes, so reproducing the Error is kinda hard. I could find the following Traceback after a while:

```
File "something.py" line ??, in power_on
TypeError: '<' not supported between instances of 'Commands' and 'Commands'
```

I honestly have no idea what is going wrong here. Do I have to switch everything to integers or do I have to ditch the queue module entirely?

Answer (score 1):

The basic `Enum` doesn't support comparisons (i.e. `<`, `>`,`<=`, `>=`).  You can either add them:

```
from enum import Enum, auto

class Commands(Enum):
    power_on = auto()
    power_off = auto()
    etc = auto()
    #
    def __lt__(self, other):
        if isinstance(other, self.__class__):
            return self._value_ < other._value_
        return NotImplemented
    #
    # same thing for __gt__, __le__, __ge__
```

or, you can use `IntEnum` instead -- but then your `Commands` will compare against normal `int`s, which may not be what you want.

Also, as a style issue, enum class names should be singular -- `Command` instead of `Commands`.

---

Disclosure:  I am the author of the [Python stdlib `Enum`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/enum.html), the [`enum34` backport](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/enum34), and the [Advanced Enumeration (`aenum`)](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/aenum)  library.

Comment: Ah okay, thank you for your answer. I'll try adding the comparison and see if it fixes the Error.